# Empty Model Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have this code

```
@if (Model.Products != null)
{

  @Html.Raw(string.Join(", ", Model.Products.Select(s => string.Format("<span>{0}</span>", s.Name))))

}
else
{
  <text>N/A</text>
}
```

Which prints a list of products separated by a comma, but the problem is that the Model.Products is never null, it can contain cero products but its never null, is there another way to compare this If statement?

Comment: @if (Model.Products != null && Model.Products.Count >0)

Comment: @bejger or perhaps `&& Model.Products.Any()`

Comment: Logic like this should not be in the view. Why not make this string a display model property, or something along those lines?

Comment: Thanks bejger, that was it, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is never null, you can use

```
@if (Model.Products.Any())
```